# Exec not returning anything when trying to run git shortlog with nodejs

Tags: git, node.js, exec

I'm trying to get the result of `git shortlog` on a repository with nodejs this way:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("cd /tmp/"+folder +" && git shortlog", {maxBuffer: 500*1024}, function(error, stdout, stderror){
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

My callback is never called with this method, the program appears processing something indefinitely.

When I launch this command in my prompt I've the results.

Trying to redirect the result to a file create an empty file :

```
"cd /tmp/"+folder +" && git shortlog > stats.txt"
```

But if I use `git log` instead I've got my results.

Do you know why my callback is never called with `git shortlog` ?

Edit :
I've the same result using spawn :

```
exec("cd /tmp/"+folder, function(err){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }

    var shortlog = spawn('git', ['shortlog']);
    shortlog.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    shortlog.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    shortlog.on('close', function (code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });
});
```

Edit 2 :
process.chdir() doesn't change anything :

```
process.chdir('/tmp/'+folder);
var shortlog = spawn('git', ['shortlog']);
shortlog.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
```

Comment: you could try swapping out exec for spawn and see what events are firing.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it, but I've the same issue.

Comment: Next stab: http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory use process.chdir instead of exec "cd ..."

Comment: Arg, thanks for this answer but I've the same behviour. I've edited my post

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`git shortlog` thinks that it has to read something from stdin, hence the indefinite wait. Try this:

```
exec('git shortlog < /dev/tty', { cwd : "/tmp/" + folder }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

Comment: For Windows, use `CON` instead of `/dev/tty`

Answer (score 3):

Since @robertklep 's answer is correct, I'm afraid it's not complete as well. 
On *nix systems, yes, you can use it with `/dev/tty` but on Windows this will throw an error like

> The system cannot find the path specified.

To solve this problem on Windows, you can simply do this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var tty = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'CON' : '/dev/tty';

exec('git shortlog < ' + tty, { cwd : '/tmp/' + folder }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(arguments);
});
```